# ¿como puedo hacer para capturar el output del pysnmp?

Tags: python

tengo el siguiente codigo, que tome de por ahi, y necesito 2 cosas porque de pysmnp no entiendo nada.
como hago captura de la salida, trate de ponerlo en un archivo de texto, pero lo toma como un tipo "None"

```
def walk(host, oid):

for (errorIndication,
     errorStatus,
     errorIndex,
     varBinds) in nextCmd(SnmpEngine(),
                          CommunityData('XXXXX'),
                          UdpTransportTarget((host, 161)),
                          ContextData(),
                          ObjectType(ObjectIdentity(oid)),
                          lookupMib=False,
                          lexicographicMode=False):

    if errorIndication:
        print(errorIndication, file=sys.stderr)
        break

    elif errorStatus:
        print('%s at %s' % (errorStatus.prettyPrint(),
                            errorIndex and varBinds[int(errorIndex) - 1][0] or '?'), file=sys.stderr)
        break

    else:
        for varBind in varBinds:
             print('%s = %s' % varBind)
```

walk('172.18.0.6', '1.3.6.1.2.1.1.9.1.2')

Comment: Te recomiendo hacer solo una pregunta por publicación. Hay un motivo de cierre que dice "Necesita ser más especifica" "Esta pregunta incluye multiples preguntas en una".

Comment: dale, elimino la 2 y la hago en otra, gracias

Comment: De nada amigo c: